# How to solve this SQL error: Every derived table must have its own alias?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What's the matter with this SQL:

```
SELECT dept_name, avg_salary
FROM    (SELECT dept_name, AVG(salary) AS avg_salary                
        FROM instructor GROUP BY dept_name)
WHERE avg_salary > 42000;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias
```

Somebody help me, thanks.

Comment: add an alias after  `SELECT (subquery) x`

Comment: Read the error message.  Don't just give up because you got one.

Comment: Same as your query: `SELECT ...... FROM (SELECT ....FROM....GROUP BY...) As D WHERE......` . The _subquery_ that is in the `FROM` clause of outer query is known as **DerivedTable**. So, for this table, you should align alias. For e.g I have used D as a alias for the derivedTable. The _query_ as a whole would be `SELECT ... FROM D WHERE...`

Answer (score 4):

By adding an alias like below

```
SELECT dept_name, avg_salary
FROM    (SELECT dept_name, AVG(salary) AS avg_salary                
        FROM instructor GROUP BY dept_name) xxx <-- Here
WHERE avg_salary > 42000;
```

Though you can modify your query like below

```
SELECT dept_name, AVG(salary) AS avg_salary 
FROM  instructor 
GROUP BY dept_name
HAVING AVG(salary) > 42000;
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is describing exactly what you have to do:

```
SELECT dept_name, avg_salary
FROM    (SELECT dept_name, AVG(salary) AS avg_salary                
        FROM instructor GROUP BY dept_name) as a
--    Add the alias HERE -------------------^^^^^
WHERE avg_salary > 42000;
```

If you use a subquery as a data source, you must assign an alias to it.

Answer (score 1):

Add an alias after the derived table:

```
FROM    (SELECT dept_name, AVG(salary) AS avg_salary                
        FROM instructor GROUP BY dept_name) as tab
```

Although you could skip the derived table and use `having` instead:

```
SELECT dept_name, AVG(salary) AS avg_salary                
FROM instructor 
GROUP BY dept_name
HAVING avg_salary > 42000;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, every derived table (in layman's terms: a subquery) must have a table alias, even if you don't use it.
Just add one, and you should be fine:

```
SELECT dept_name, avg_salary
FROM   (SELECT   dept_name, AVG(salary) AS avg_salary                
        FROM     instructor 
        GROUP BY dept_name) t -- t is a table alias
WHERE avg_salary > 42000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down so you understand what this error is about and what the error message means. This way you will understand what to do the next time you get this message as well.

This part of the query is a derived table:

```
(SELECT dept_name, AVG(salary) AS avg_salary                
            FROM instructor GROUP BY dept_name)
```

That means it is acting as a table in the query. For the database engine to work properly, all tables have to have a name. That is why it needs you to add an alias.

So your query becomes:

```
SELECT a.dept_name, a.avg_salary
FROM    (SELECT dept_name, AVG(salary) AS avg_salary                
        FROM instructor GROUP BY dept_name) as a
WHERE a.avg_salary > 42000;
```

Note that I used the alias through the query and not just to name the table. This is because it is a best practice to  reference all fields with the table name or alias that they are associated with. It is not necessary when you only have one table as this one or if the field name is only in one table, but it helps with maintenance (trust me you don't want to try to figure out which table a field came from when you have 12 tables joined together) and it a good habit to get into all of the time.

Answer (score 0):

For every subquery  we need to give alias name,then only it will work

SELECT dept_name, avg_salary
FROM    (SELECT dept_name, AVG(salary) AS avg_salary
        FROM instructor GROUP BY dept_name) as samplename
WHERE avg_salary > 42000;

Thank you.